# PHP is outputting table all on one line

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, word-wrap

The script is supposed to take all of the pictures in a folder and output the first six of them into a table. Then I would like to add a little next button so one can view the rest of the images, but currently the script is just spitting them all out on one line.  All of them, not just the six I want.  In addition to that the code is also appearing at the bottom of the webpage, below a lot of code that comes after it in the document.

The PHP

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$directory = 'images/gallery/';
$files1 = scandir($directory);
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$z = 0; 
echo"<table><tr>";
foreach ($files1 as $filename) {
   if ($z == $x + 6) {
    break 2;
    }
    if ($x==1 || $x==0)
    {
        $x=$x+1;
    }
     else {
        if ($y == $x + 3) {
            echo "<td><a data-lightbox='gallery' href='images/gallery/$filename'><img src='images/gallery/$filename'></a></td></tr><tr>";
            $y = $x;
            $x=$x+1;
        } else {
            echo "<td><a data-lightbox='gallery' href='images/gallery/$filename'><img src='images/gallery/$filename'></a></td>";
            $x = $x+1;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" >
    <title>Perspective by Daniel Streich</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/css.css">
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $active = "Art";
    include ('menu.php');
    ?>

    <div class="wrapperRegular">
        <p class="bigTitle">
            Perspective by Daniel
        </p>
        <p class='actualText'>
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
        </p>
        <?php
        include ('gallery.php');
        ?>
        <br>
        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &#169; Perspective by Daniel
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS

```
#wrapperRegular {
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
}
p.bigTitle {
font-family: 'alluraregular';
font-size: 500%;
text-align: center;
color: 898888;
line-height: .33em;
}
p.actualText {
font-family: 'alluraregular';
color: 898888;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

table {
font-family: 'alluraregular';
color: 898888;
font-size: 1.5em;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
border:5px;
}
```

Comment: What does the **output** html look like?

Comment: `$z = 0` and `$x` is only increasing so you will never reach your `break` at `$z == $x + 6`. Seems an awfully complicated loop to just echo 2 rows of 3. Just use one constantly increasing counter and check the modulus operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't closing the `<table>` tag in the PHP. This means the the `<p>`s are going *inside* the table. Most browsers disagree with this invalid HTML by putting the non-table elements *ahead* of the table, which is why the table is sinking to the bottom.

Close the `</table>` in your PHP and it should work fine.

Why not try this instead:

```
<?php

$directory = 'images/gallery/';
$files1 = scandir($directory);
$x = 1;
echo"<table><tr>";
foreach ($files1 as $filename) {
   if ($x <= 6) {
       if ($x % 3==0) {
           echo "</tr><tr>";
       }
       echo "<td><a data-lightbox='gallery' href='images/gallery/$filename'><img src='images/gallery/$filename'></a></td>";
       $y = $x;
       $x=$x+1;
   } else {
       break;
   }
}
echo"</tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: maybe add a break if x > 6 aswell.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I have to skip the first two elements because the scandir will put the the first two entries as .. and then I have two broken pictures

Answer (score 0):

A solution to make rows of 3, skipping the directories:

```
$count = 0;
echo "<table><tr>";
foreach ($files1 as $filename)
{
  if (is_file($filename))
  {
    if ($count && ($count % 3 === 0))
    {
      echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

    echo "<td><a data-lightbox='gallery' href='images/gallery/$filename'><img src='images/gallery/$filename'></a></td></tr><tr>";

    $count++
    if ($count >= 6)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```